# Dynamic edit distance

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I tried to make a dynamic algorithm to calculate the distance between two strings. For example, if I have "casa" and "cara", the output should be 2 (1 insert + 1 deletion), but I get 1. This is the algorithm:

```js
public static int distance(String word1, String word2) {
    int dp[][] = new int[m+1][n+1];
    for (int i=0; i<=m; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
        if (i==0)
          dp[i][j] = j;  
        else if (j==0)
          dp[i][j] = i; 
        else if (str1.charAt(i-1) == str2.charAt(j-1))
          dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];
        else {
          int rep=dp[i-1][j-1];
          int ins=dp[i][j-1];
          int del=dp[i-1][j];
          dp[i][j] = 1 + Math.min(rep, Math.min(ins, del));
        }
      }
    }
    return dp[m][n];
  }
```

Could you please find me which code causes the bug?
Why the output of this algorithm is 1 instead of 2 using the strings "casa" and "cara"?

Comment: There is no question in your post

Comment: Why the output of this algorithm is 1 instead of 2 using the strings "casa" and "cara"?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. m, n, str1 and str2 are not defined. I guess m is size of word1, n is size of word2, str1 is word1 and str2 is word2. You also didn't define which alogrithm you want to implement (looks like Levenshtein distance). In the else part you define rep (I guess for replacement), ins (I guess for insertion) and del (I guess for deletion). So in my opinion the algorithm works correct because you only have to do one replacement ("s" -> "r"), so the result is 1 (Levenshtein distance between those strings is definitely 1).